# Effects of internet connection speeds on server queries

Tags: linux, mysql, connection, internet, query

Can my internet connection significantly effect queries run on phpmyadmin? I am currently 18 down and 30 up. I switched internet connections today and noticed a deep drop in query performance.

The query that I am running is `SELECT * FROM table`. Simple. The table has one row of data. The MySQL server is on the same server as everything else. It is a VPS. Godaddy hosts. I dont have any other information.

Centos 6.3
MySQL 5.1
PhpMyAdmin 3.4

Okay used google tools to inspect the XHR going out and coming in and this is what it reported. `{"success":true,"message":"<div class=\"success\">Your SQL query has been executed successfully ( Query took 0.0033 sec )<\/div>","sql_query":"<div id=\"result_query\" align=\"\">\n<div class=\"success\">Your SQL query has been executed successfully ( Query took 0.0033 sec ) SNIP..................."}`. So apparently my server is fine.

The strange thing is though.. The returned XHR comes back exactly as soon as I execute the query on the page. It comes back within less than a second. Why PhpMyadmin does not report the change immediately. I am going to try a re-install.

Comment: When you talk about `a deep drop in query performance` are you talking about the actual length of the query running on the server, or are you talking about the length of time before the server shows you the results of the query? If memory serves, there should be a query history section somewhere in phpMyAdmin with execution times. These should be relatively consistent.

Comment: Okay good point. I made an edit.

Comment: Honestly, phpMyAdmin is *bad*. You should consider uninstalling it and leaving it uninstalled.

Answer (score 5):

No. If the server is on the same machine as your phpMyAdmin install your remote machines bandwidth will not impact the performance of your queries.

As a side note, phpMyAdmin is the devil. There are lots of security vulnerabilities in it and it's rarely secured properly. You might want to consider ditching it and learning the mysql command-line syntax.

Answer (score 2):

The connection can really affect the speed, especially with the PHPMyAdmin->Browser connection. Depending on the PHPMyAdmin version, it can use AJAX, or not, and so you may experience as much overhead as sending an entire PHPMyAdmin UI sans cached stuff, or still quite a bit of overhead involving the fluff surrounding the tables. While the query itself has finished, it takes a while to feed all of that data to your browser.  I suggest you try to use an external client and see how that can affect it, or see whether you are using near the maximum practical throughput of your connection when you try to select thousands of rows.  You can compare the used bandwidth with that when downloading a large file. With that said, I agree that PHPMyAdmin can be ditched for something more efficient.

Comment: This isn't exactly correct. This does not affect query execution time. It could impact how long it takes you to view the query, but the length of time that the query actually runs will be unchanged.

Comment: @MDMarra I had left that out as I had assumed users would assume that, but thanks for pointing that out.